# return statement in ternary operator c++

Tags: c++, return, ternary

I wrote the absolute function using ternary operator as follows

```
int abs(int a) {
 a >=0 ? return a : return -a;
}
```

I get the following error messages

```
../src/templates.cpp: In function ‘int abs(int)’:
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘return’
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token
../src/templates.cpp:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
../src/templates.cpp:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
```

If I write like this

```
return a>=0 ? a : -a;
```

I don't get any error.
What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The second and third arguments to the ternary operator are expressions, not statements.

```
 return a
```

is a statement

Comment: The first argument to the ternary operator is also an expression, of course.  The latter two might be expressions of type `void`, though.

Answer (score 45):

Your syntax is incorrect. 
It should be

```
if (a >=0)
    return a;
else
    return -a;
```

or the way you wanted it:

```
return a >=0 ? a : -a;
```

Answer (score 23):

> What's the difference between the two?

One is correct syntax, the other is not.

Comment: Yes, but **why** is it incorrect? Why can't you use ```return``` in the ternary operator?

Comment: @H-005 this is due to language grammar; the ternary operator is written in a specific way that expects expressions not statements

Answer (score 11):

`?:` is an operator that takes three expressions and evaluates them in some way to produce a result. `return a` is not an *expression* (it's a *statement*), so your first form doesn't work. It's the same as you can't put `return` in the arguments of other operators: `return a + return b` will also not work.

If you want the returns in the separate branches, use `if` instead:

```
if (a >=0)
   return a;
else
   return -a;
```

Answer (score 9):

Return is a statement and cannot be used where a value is expected.

You must use expressions (which usually yield a value) in the three components of the ternary operator.