# Why can't I use return in my ternary expression but I can in a regular if-else statement?

Tags: c++, return-value, ternary-operator

I am writing a simple factorial function to practice recursion within c++. 
I wanted to write it in ternary format but it was not working so I wrote it out first to see if it worked the more traditional way.

Ternary Format:

```
   num > 1 ? num * factorial(num-1) : return 1;
```

Traditional :

```
   if (num > 1){
    return num * factorial(num-1);
   }
   else {
    return 1; 
   }
```

I am simply printing the result of factorial(5) which should display 120. While it works for the second it does not for the first. Why can I not use return in the ternary format? Or, am I using it wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918203/return-statement-in-ternary-operator-c

Comment: Because `return` isn't an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use factorial just fine in the conditional form, but you can't use `return`. `return` is a *statement*, whereas the conditional operator expects expressions. Conveniently, the conditional operator itself is an expression, which lets you do this.

```
return num > 1 ? num * factorial(num-1) : 1;
```

Note that we're returning the result of the *whole* expression, not just the `num > 1` piece. If I wanted to be redundant with parentheses, I could do this, which is semantically equivalent.

```
return (num > 1 ? num * factorial(num-1) : 1);
```